# WPEWebkit interaction with other processes

Tags: c++, webkit, ipc

So, I'm a bit lost on the WPEWebkit and WPEFramework and I need help from you guys...
I need to parse an HTML file (already accomplished) and call a plugin running on WPEFramework. How can I do that? Through IPC? Are there any examples of that?
Is there a better way (besides RPC) to implement such mechanism?
The communication between the two processes is bidirectional, meaning that I will receive notifications or events from the other side.

Thanks in advance!